# /dev/pts/* group writable in permissions but not in reality

Tags: permissions, pty, permission-denied

Whenether I execute the command `ls -lh` on `/dev/pts` I get:

```
crw--w---- 1 usr1 tty 136, 0 Mar 16 16:41 0
```

Which does seem to allow users that belong to the same group as usr1 to write that into that.

When I tried `echo test >> /dev/pts/0` I got "Permission denied" even though I am a member of the usr1's group.

Shouldn't I be able to write into that pseudoterminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
crw--w---- 1 usr1 tty 136, 0 Mar 16 16:41 0
```

It allows writing for user *usr1* and.. users belonging to group *tty*, not users belonging to *usr1* group.

So, on the other user, which fails to write on `/dev/pts/0`, run `id` to make sure it is in the *tty* group. If not, add it in `/etc/group` on the line beginning with `tty:`

Comment: I had a nobble cause, I was trying to mess around with some of my collegues. I failed to see the different group, but changing the permissions through their console while they are away can also do the trick

Comment: For such a noble cause, I would use: `export PROMPT_COMMAND='if test $(($LINENO % 10)) -eq 1; then telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl; fi'` in order to make them watch StarWars in text mode every 10th command run in bash.

Comment: Haha, very nice

Answer (score 0):

No.

User and group are listed in the same order as the permission bits: user first, then group.

The file `0` belongs to the user `usr1` and the group `tty`.  There is no relationship to the *group* `usr1`.